# worthwhile + a noun/gerund

Tags: meaning

This is correct.

> This place is worthwhile visiting.

What about this?

> This place is worthwhile a visit.

Comment: I'd prefer "This place with worth visiting" and "This place is worth a visit"

Comment: I am having no issue with your preference, but it's not about preferring. "This place is worthwhile visiting." - is grammatically correct sentence. I agree that one can detect a difference between it and "This place is worth visiting." but it's not the point.

Comment: @user1425 Your first example is grammatically OK. Gerund-participles are virtually excluded from being complements to adjectives, with a few exceptions like "worth" and "worthwhile". But they don't take NPs as complements, so your second example is ungrammatical.

Comment: @user1425 JamesK is tactfully suggesting that your first example, which you say is correct, is not as solid as you think. "This place is worth visiting" is definitely correct, but as a native (US) English speaker, I have a hard time parsing "This place is worthwhile visiting" as correct English. It's certainly not how people normally speak, in my experience. Since the first example sheds some light on the second, it's *worth commenting* on its correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No of course it is not.

We do not place the adjective before the article, but before the noun.

So 'this place is a worthwhile visit'.

'visiting' is a gerund, which is to say a verb functioning as a noun, and it does not take an article, hence 'a worthwhile visit' but 'worthwhile visiting'.